# A Django model that only has many to many fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to store a User's ID and the ID of a Listing in a table. I am new to web development and to me, this seems like a good time to use a `ManyToManyField`:

```py
class Watchlist(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    listing = models.ManyToManyField(Listing)
```

When I try to save a new entry in the database, by doing this:

```py
            listing_id = self.kwargs['pk']
            item = Listing.objects.get(id=listing_id)
            user_object = self.request.user

            add_to_watchlist = Watchlist(user = user_object, listing = item)
            add_to_watchlist.save()
```

I get the error:
`TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use user.set() instead.`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I have followed the example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) as much as possible.

Comment: Try first creating a Watchlist object obj. and then add seperately, 
obj = WatchList().save()
obj.user.add(user_object)
obj.listing.add(item).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not directly assign a value to a `ManyToManyField`, but use the [**`.add(…)`** method <sup>[Djang-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) as the error indicates:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

item = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

watchlist = Watchlist.objects.create()
watchlist.user.add(request.user)
watchlist.listing.add(item)
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: Since a `ManyToManyField` refers to a *collection* of elements,
> `ManyToManyField`s are normally given a *plural* name. You thus might want
> to consider renaming <s>`user`</s> to `users`.